# Nillable/throwing convenience initializer causing Core Data problems?

Tags: swift, core-data, initialization

I have a Core Data model with an entity whose parent is an abstract entity. The implementations of the classes are in Swift. There is a single property and a single relationship established in the abstract entity, with some other properties and a relationship on the concrete entity.

I'm hitting a strange issue now. When I add a nillable convenience initializer (`public convenience init?`) or a throwing one (`public convenience init(...) throws`) to the concrete entity, I start getting an `NSInvalidArgumentException` like so:

> -[MyModel.ConcreteEntity setAbstractAttribute:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aa75a10

When I I remove the `?` and `throws` from the signature, I don't get that exception. What can I do to allow this?